# Reference-type class field in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make a model like this:

```
public class Competition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GameResult> PlayedGames { get; set; }
}
```

where GameResult is a class with simple fields.
I add one:

```
context.Competitions.Add(new Competition()
            {
                Name = "Default competition",
                Description = "This is a sample of a competition rules. Hope its seems good :3",
                PlayedGames = new List<GameResult> {new GameResult {Id = 1, LeftPlayer = "left", RightPlayer = "right", LeftScore = 10, RightScore = 20} },
                IsActive = true
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
```

When i try to get value from context.Competitions, other fields have value, but "PlayedGames" is null.

I guess this is because its a reference-type class.
I need to make another table with foreign key?
How can i do this in "Code First"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your navigation property as `virtual`:

```
public class Competition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameResult> PlayedGames { get; set; }
}
```

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) the requirements that your entities must follow. This way EF will create a proxy class derived from your class and uses it instead of your original class that handles [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) and track changes.

Another way to load a related property is using [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager):

```
var query= context.Competitions
                  .Include(c=>c.PlayedGames) //using this method you are going to load the related entity as part of your query
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i just used "Include" and its works. TY. It means that GameResult was added in DB, but to get it, we need to "ask" to include? ok, nice :)